# Resize the page when I resize the window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a problem with my page.
On Facebook or Twitter, when you resize your browser window, the page looks like when it was not resized, how I can do that on my page? 
For example if I have this code and I resize my window, the box is always in the middle of the page and It's not "blocked".
Try to resize the page with my code, the box will move and change dimension, I want to avoid this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
<body>

<div style="width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; margin-top: -50px; margin-left: -50px; background:#ccc;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

What I can do? Do I have to use javascript?

Comment: Could you give a screen shot of what you mean?

Comment: Sorry Alberto, i don't understand what you want.

Comment: @Alberto, are you talking about [responsive web design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design "Responsive Web Design")?

Comment: Try to resize the page with my code, the box will move and change dimension, I want to avoid this ...
@Tyanna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking to give a minimum width, and minimum height, forcing your element to overflow.

I have forced a non-responsive layout, which seems to be your intention:
There is a fiddle of the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/paperblankets/YTk6t/

And the code reformatted like yours here:

```
<html>
<body>
<span style="display:block;min-width:280px;">
<div style="    width:250px;
    /* Random dimentions */
    height:200px;
    /* Random dimentions */
    display:inline-block;
    /*Allow Elements to sit next to each other */
    margin: 10px;
    /* Slight padding to see the elements  */
    background:#ccc;
    /* Slight color to see the elements */
    overflow: visible;
    /* Allow elements to overflow, and scroll bar to appear */"></div>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Please look over the comment in the Fiddle I linked to, it breaks down which rule is causing which effects.

Comment: Try to resize the page with my code, the box will move and change dimension, I want to avoid this @Levi

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/paperblankets/YTk6t/

Comment: Bingo, I'm going to apply this on my page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use either JavaScript (See the `onResize` event) or CSS media queries.

Since your question is vague, we can't help much more than that.

Comment: Since OP question is vague, i can't help much more than that either.

Comment: Try to resize the page with my code, the box will move and change dimension, I want to avoid this @Mooseman